# Change IXLCell number format from decimal point (.) to decimal comma (,) - c#

Tags: c#, excel, cell, number-formatting, decimal-point

So it's pretty simple..(at least I thought so...)

I'm trying to export some data to excel from my app and I can't find a solution how to change decimal point to decimal comma (this is also an European standard)

This is the code currently and numbers are written like **12,561.00**

```
var cell = worksheet.Cell(i, 1);
cell.SetDataType(XLDataType.Number);
cell.Style.NumberFormat.SetFormat("#,##0.00");
```

I can't find solution for changing this code to show it like **12.561,00**

I've tried obvious solution like this and similiar variations:

```
cell.Style.NumberFormat.SetFormat("#.##0,00");
```

Also I've tried these solutions from this [link](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/12273/spreadsheet-document-api/examples/formatting/how-to-specify-number-or-date-format-for-cell-content)

I suppose I have to change format number globally in whole worksheet or workbook but I couldn't find any option that could work.

Thanks!

Comment: remember this is depending on your system localization setup. if it is about represent the number in UI, it is fine to change, but if you need to do some calculations later and you enforce changing it, you end up getting wrong numbers.